Scene in Image Comics of convicted killer sent as an involuntary space explorer
Back in the 90s, I recall a scene, from an Image Comic I believe (I thought Vanguard #1, but it appears not) where a convicted killer has been sent in a small habitat out into the solar system to collect data. Essentially a life sentence without parole but an attempt to serve society, still. The criminal makes threats about President Carter. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

I haven’t read it, but could this be “Hard Time” by Steve Gerber?

@Bitterfiction - That comic seems to be about a boy with psychic powers. I don't see anything relating to space or space travel at all.
